# How to reproduce a tileView

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been seeing a bunch of website with something called tile view (I think).
The idea is you have multiple element on a html page with different width and height.

And you have a javascript that will organize randomly each element next to each other to maximize the number of element you can see at once.

An example is http://www.clipboard.com/feeds (You may have to select tile view next to the search bar)

Is there a jquery plugin already? or a native javascript that do something similar?

If not what kind of algorithm would you use to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a jquery plugin already?

Yes, there is a jQuery for that "already".

> or a native javascript that do something similar?

Inside that jQuery there is "native" javascript that does exactly that.

> If not what kind of algorithm would you use to do it?

It's explained IIRC, was a blog post outlining how it works. You would need to look that up however.

---

- [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) (this is probably *exactly* what you're looking for)
- [jQuery Distribute Plugin](https://github.com/tommoor/distribute-jquery-plugin)

Comment: Inside jquery there is native javascript YES but it use the jquery library... If I want to use prototype for example, it would be great not to have to load jquery on the side just for that.